# Sitecore Search - Empty Analytics

Tags: sitecore-search

I'm using Sitecore Search. I was able to index content and inquire about that through the REST API.

I've an issue, when I open the Sitecore Search Analytics Tab every counter is 0, like the following image:

[image]

How do I enable the Sitecore Search Analytics for the site?

Any of the Analytics counters should show a value greater than 0? When?

When the user searches for a keyword? Or maybe I need to register an event by calling the Event API immediately after doing the search?

When does the counter "Requests" increase its value?

Thanks in advance community

Answer (score 1):

Correct, the Sitecore Search uses the **Events** for generating analytic dashboards, insights into your search performance and even driving personalisation. So, to track your visitor interactions with the search functionality you must call the **Events API** and correctly pass the associated **Event** object to it.

Here is a simple example of how to track an event with the Events API:

```
POST /event/{ckey}/v4/publish
{
 "data": 
    {
      "name": "<event name>",
      "action": "<event action>",
      "action_sub_type": "<event action subtype>",
      "client_time_ms": xxx,
      "user_id": "<unique ID of visitor>",
      "value": {
        "context": {
          "browser": {
            "app_type": "browser",
            "device": "<mobile_desktop>",
            "user_agent": "<user_agent>"
            },
          "geo": {
            "ip": "xx.xx.xx.xx"
            },
          "page": {
            "uri": "<URL of the current page>"
            }
          },
        "entities": [
            {
              "entity_type": "content, product",
              "id": "<External unique identifier for the entity>",
              "uri": "<URI of the entity>"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
}
```

Read more about how to track events using the Events API [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/search/en/developers/search-developer-guide/using-the-events-api-to-track-events.html).